# EXCEL Create timeline chart using variation of single value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-charts

I want to create a line chart that shows the evolution of a dynamic value present in my excel. That value is updated based on a webpage and I want to show how it is evolving day by day. It can use the value it has at 12am or something like that.

[image: Values]

In this case I want a line for each of those values, where the y axis is the percentage it has and the x is the day. So on X for today it appear 8.13% for the first value and tommorow the value it has.

[[image: Example Result(https://i.stack.imgur.com/kvamc.png)]

Not exactly like this one but similar with %.

Comment: What's the formula you are using to draw the web information into those cells in your screenshot?

Comment: If you refer to the chart in the second print, it is only an example from internet. The values from the first print are based on a api call using importdata and some transformations to it.

Comment: In that case you probably have to use a vba macro that creates a hard copy of the web data every day that workbook is opened